# How update a SwiftUI List without animation

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to update a SwiftUI List without any insert animation.
My `List` is getting its data from an `@EnvironmentObject`
I already tried to wrap the `List` itself and the `PassthroughSubject.send()` in a `withAnimation(.empty)` block but this does not help.

A very very dirty workaround is to call `UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)` (yes, UIKit has impact on SwiftUI), but there must be a SwiftUI-like way to set custom insert animations.

Comment: The question is, if this feature is already present and I can't find it.

Comment: could you please share code?

Answer (score 12):

While the answer provided by DogCoffee works, it does so in an inefficient manner. Sometimes we do have to force the system to do what we want by being inefficient. In the case of implicit animations in SwiftUI, there is a better way to disable them.

Using the [Transaction](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/transaction) mechanism in SwiftUI, we can define an extension that can be applied to any view. This will disable animations for the view and any children.

For the list view example, this avoids replacing all the data in the list with a new, but identical copies.

```
extension View {
     
    func animationsDisabled() -> some View {
        return self.transaction { (tx: inout Transaction) in
            tx.disablesAnimations = true
            tx.animation = nil
        }.animation(nil)
    }
}
```

Try applying this extension to your list, or the parent containing view. You may have to experiment to find which view is ideal.

```
List {
    // for each etc
}.animationsDisabled()
```

Comment: I use that : `List { ... }.animation(nil)`. I'm using Xcode 11.5

Answer (score 8):

This works, just place `.id(UUID())` at the end of your list

```
List {
    // for each etc
}.id(UUID())
```

Sort of like reloadData for UIKit

Comment: This achieves the desired effect, but ... why?

Comment: It seems like it just causes it to redraw the entire list on every update (because the ID is always changing because its a new UUID every time), so this seems very much like a hack.

Comment: SwiftUI usually does a DIFF between the current list and new list to determine inserted and removed rows but by setting a new UUID each time it thinks it has a new list so doesn't bother trying to do the DIFF.

Answer (score 1):

on tvOS this works for me:

```
List {
    ...
}
    .animation(.none)
```

Comment: What's the benefit of this syntax over similar variations previously answered? E.g., why might someone prefer this over `.animation(nil)`, as suggested by Gene Z. Ragan?

Comment: @Gert Arnold - i did try the code and it is working for me in tvOS, usually i send tons of code and fully working examples, but i was told that users seeking for one liner as much as possible (i also like small short concise answers, so i decided to try and supply one myself), i will fix my answer to clarify it

Comment: @Jeremy Caney - i prefer to control the code and use apple's properties and values so if future SwiftUI release will change the API i can be notified about it, simply setting to nil (no value) won't cause compiler to notify me if that option (none) has changed or is deprecated or not supported anymore, also if that option has gone then using nil may cause unpredictable behavior

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5.8:**

`.animation()` still works with *some* native SwiftUI views, like Text(), Image(), etc. and it is not deprecated there. It is deprecated if you try to use it on your custom views.
You can switch to `withAnimation` or `animation(_:value:)` but you can also make your custom SwiftUI view conform to `Equatable`.

```
struct CustomView: View, Equatable {
    var body: some View {

    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

```
.animate(nil)
```

you can find more info on https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/animating-views-and-transitions

Comment: I am afraid setting .animation(nil) to neither List itself nor items in it makes the 'folding' animation gone when new items are loaded and updated to the list.

Comment: i think he meant .animation(.none)